# cropping image from the right css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to crop an image from the right side as the window resizes.  If you go to http://www.claymation.azularis.com/Work and look at the banner image, pay attention as you resize the window from full width to until you see the videos going from 3 in a row to 2 in a row, now as you keep resizing you are able to scroll to the right, I would like to remove that and I'm not sure how.

Here is the how I control the image:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="header-main"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="image missing" /></h1></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
html body #page-wrap header {
  height: 17rem;
}
html body #page-wrap header .header-main {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 102.4rem;
}
html body #page-wrap header .header-main img {
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -200%;
}
```

Now I fully understand that this scrolling effect comes from `min-width: 102.4rem;` however, if I do not have that put there then the image keeps resizing from left and right and I lose the letters on the left.

How can I keep the current effect and remove the scrolling?

P.S.  I am trying to stay away from JS/JQuery for this.

Comment: Try to use background-image. Could be easily done then with background-position.

Comment: can you give me an example of how you would do it with background position and keep the effects that I have?  Have the image crop left and right until it hits 1024 pixels and then only resize on the right?

Comment: If you just want a bada*s solution, add body { overflow-x: hidden; } and then do your arrangements. B|

Comment: @MehulMohan that worked like a charm, mind posting it as a solution so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Sure :) Glad it worked, but I think its not the permanent solution. You should look upon code quality. But if it works, it ain't stupid B| :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a solution, add body { overflow-x: hidden; } and then do your arrangements. Cheers!